# P5 SVG imageMode

Tags: javascript, svg, p5.js

I load my mapbox-Link like this and it works:

```
var mapimg;

function preload () {
  mapimg = loadImage('mapbox-LINK');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024,720);
  translate(width /2, height / 2);
  imageMode (CENTER); 
  image(mapimg, 0,0);
}
```

But when I change `craeteCanvas()` to `craeteCanvas( , , SVG)` it jumps away and behaves strange. I'm using zenozeng to render the .svg Canvas.
I think it is the `imageMode(CENTER)` that doesnt work in this enviroment. How can I center my Image again?

Comment: My Map: https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/foliran/cjnrcb1pm1vbw2rqkbw3o5uog/static/10.4209538,51.1657564,5/1024x720?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZm9saXJhbiIsImEiOiJjam5yZXA0Z2gwNnlmM2twcDJrNnlxdHJkIn0.vSpVuibxadIaVGb4JiPn_w

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're using SVG mode? I don't see that mentioned in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas) anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are translating your canvas to center `translate(width /2, height / 2);` then drawing the image. If you want the image centered, just keep the canvas on its original (0,0), and default imageMode(CORNER)

```
var mapimg;

function preload () {
  mapimg = loadImage('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/foliran/cjnrcb1pm1vbw2rqkbw3o5uog/static/10.4209538,51.1657564,5/1024x720?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZm9saXJhbiIsImEiOiJjam5yZXA0Z2gwNnlmM2twcDJrNnlxdHJkIn0.vSpVuibxadIaVGb4JiPn_w');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024,720,SVG);
  // translate(width /2, height / 2); //no need to translate
  // imageMode (CORNER); //no need to imageMode, as it's default
  image(mapimg, 0,9);
}
```

I'm not familiar with [p5.js-svg](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) but be careful with all the different implications of rendering using the p5.js canvas vs using this svg mode.